Add two headers at the same time in request
i have this CTF challenge that tell me to put two Referer at the same request in burp suite to pass and get the flag
Referer: https://internal/admin.letmepass.com
Referer: THE_HUNTERS_ARE_AWAKE_SO_PLEASE_HELP_ME

When I was searching the internet I read RFC 7230,Which explains the mechanism of use multiple headers with the same field name, But that didn't work for me
Does anyone have an idea about the topic?

When you're trying to break security, you don't always want to follow standards. Often, the security bug is how something copes when you don't do what the standard tells you to.

There is more than one way to affects the heades, so that there is a possibility to add two headers of the same type, with the presence of another new condition, which is manipulating the header letters.
in my situation the right solution was
Refererr: https://internal/admin.letmepass.com
Referer: THE_HUNTERS_ARE_AWAKE_SO_PLEASE_HELP_ME

